# Resolve all fields in one resolver V.S. resolve field in each resolver

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Here is my `typeDefs`:

```js
const typeDefs: string = `
  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    authorId: ID!
    author: User
  }

  type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]!
  }
`;

export { typeDefs };
```

`resolvers`:

```js
import { IResolvers } from 'graphql-tools';
import { IBook } from './db';

const resolvers1: IResolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (_, args, { db }): Promise<IBook[]> => {
      return db.books.map(book => {
        book.author = db.users.find(user => book.authorId === user.id);
        return book;
      });
    }
  }
};

const resolvers2: IResolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (_, args, { db }): Promise<IBook[]> => {
      return db.books;
    }
  },
  Book: {
    author: (book, args, { db }) => {
      return db.users.find(user => book.authorId === user.id);
    }
  }
};

export { resolvers1, resolvers2 };
```

Within `resolvers1`, it resolves all fields of `Book`. (Add `author` field to `book`)

Within `resolvers2`, it resolves each field of `Book` in the independent resolver.

I find both `resovlers1` and `resolvers2` work fine. I can get the correct response like this:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "id": "02wDZbBuMi",
        "title": "Ea repellendus",
        "authorId": "hhP2TtobM",
        "author": {
          "id": "hhP2TtobM",
          "name": "Mrs. Destiney Kerluke"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "tC3uPfKfUZ",
        "title": "Consectetur fugit",
        "authorId": "k9IHZAtld8",
        "author": {
          "id": "k9IHZAtld8",
          "name": "Mr. Rene Heidenreich"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What's the difference between them? Are these two ways correct? If not, why?

Comment: In GraphQL you want to use the resolver2 approach and use [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) to make the approach performant. Maybe just experiment with it a bit and you will find out for yourself how this works best once your server grows bigger. There are also multiple videos about dataloader in Youtube.

Comment: Yeah. I know `dataloader` and `N+1` query issue. But I think the most important reason why use `resolver2` is @Gabriel Bleu's answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resolver1` is a trade off of complexity for performance. The main argument for resolver one is that databases usually have joins that `resolver2` is not able to use. The book + author query can for example be expressed in a single SQL statement. This is a *huge* performance benefit over version 2 even with Dataloader. Now one could argue that we don't know if the author field is even needed. But we can get to know that using the `resolveInfo` argument. It is possible to write a function that quickly inspects the resolveInfo and tells us if a field is present in the subselection:

```
hasSelection(fieldName: string, resolveInfo: GraphQLResolveInfo): boolean
```

Then we can use this function to check if we should do a join.

```
books: (_, args, { db }, resolveInfo): Promise<IBook[]> => {
  if (hasSelection('author', resolveInfo)) {
    // Just an example, there is some more transformation needed
    return db.query('SELECT ... FROM book JOIN author ON book.authorId = author.id');
  }
  return db.query('SELECT ... FROM book');
}
```

This will probably be more performant by the factor of two. There are actually a lot of companies doing this because performance is key sometimes. If the example gets more complicated then the complexity rises significantly and I would not make such optimisations without determining it as a bottleneck first. On the other hand there are a lot of projects out there that work on "native GraphQL" that means they are turning GraphQL queries directly into Database queries.

Comment: Last night, I also think to use `resolver1` + `arguments` to decide what response data structure like. Which means include `author` or not. But if there are many fields. This resolver will be full of `if...else...` statements. It's bad.

Comment: If the related data is to only be retrieved from another service, say via an http call, then this approach won't have any benefits since you'll still be making a separate call in addition to the extra custom code, typically handled by the graphql engine for you.

Answer (score 2):

`resolver2` is better because it will not make useless calls to database if you don't include `author` in your request.

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you. This is a most important reason. Any other reasons or disadvantages of `resolver1`?